# MediaPlayer doens't work properly

Tags: android

In my app i added a sound when a button is clicked

This is the class that manages the sound

```
public class GestoreSuoni{
MediaPlayer mp; 

    public void playSound(Context context,int sound){
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);
         mp.start();        
    }
}
```

and in my main activity I  call the method playSound for all of my buttons

```
button_name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        gestoreSuoni.eseguiSuono(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.tieni_suono);
    }               
});
```

At first it works, but after 20-30 clicks on my buttons, I can't hear sound anymore and i get this message from LogCat: Mediaplayer error (- 19,0).

What does is mean?

Thanks

Comment: May be it will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440654/how-do-i-read-microphone-samples-on-an-android-phone/11499453#11499453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please release the memory when it stops. You are getting this error due to `out of memory` as you are `allocating memory every time` when you touch the button for playing again.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example suggested by Ilya Demidov and the advice of Chinmoy Debnath I add this part of code to the method that manages the MediaPlayer

```
public class GestoreSuoni{
MediaPlayer mp; 

    public void playSound(Context context,int sound){

           //new code/////////
       if (mp!=null) {
           mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
           ///////////////////

         mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);
         mp.start();        
    }
}
```

Now it seems to work. I hope I have solved (with your help) the problem correctly